# UIPickerView not displaying data or calling viewForRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am dynamically adding data to a pickerview as information becomes available. Though I am adding data to my array and calling `[picker reloadAllComponents]` the pickerview does not show  any data.

I also noticed that neither of the following Delegates are getting called:

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
```

Here is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  _pickerData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  _ActiveDevice = [[NSString alloc]init];

  // Connect data

  self.DevicePicker.dataSource = self;
  self.DevicePicker.delegate = self;

}
```

Here is the method that loads my hidden PickerView (I have it defaulted to hide until a button is pushed)

```
- (IBAction)FanDrop:(id)sender {
    [self printFromCoreData];
    [self.DevicePicker reloadAllComponents];
    if (_DeviceBox) _DeviceBox.hidden = !_DeviceBox.hidden;
}
```

I load the array the is the datasource for the DevicePicker using what is found in coredata This all seems to work as I can find information when logging what is in the array. Also when clicking the accept button even though nothing is showing the correct data gets loaded thus telling me that everything but the display portion of my code is working correct.

Any insight - I'm open to try almost anything.

After one comment I realized I neglected to include, in my question, the delegates. SO here they are:

```
// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //return _pickerData[row];
    return [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    return [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Here is how I am adding the array pickerData:

```
@interface CMTViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_pickerData;
}
```

Here is the CoreData method I use to load _pickerData:

```
-(void)printFromCoreData{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"DeviceData"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


    for (NSManagedObject *info in _devices) {

    NSString *item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@ %2$@",[info valueForKey:@"name"], [info valueForKey:@"ipAddress"]];

        if (![_pickerData containsObject:item]) {
            [_pickerData addObject:item];
        }
    }

     NSLog(@"_pickerData length %lu", (unsigned long)[_pickerData count]);
    [self.DevicePicker reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Here is the view of what happens in the simulator (or on my phone) when I push the fans button:

[image]

Comment: Have you included - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)minPicker {
    return //your number;
} ?

Comment: That too. Are they not in your project?

Comment: Apple docs: 

Called by the picker view when it needs the number of components. (required)
Parameters 
pickerView 
The picker view requesting the data.
Returns 
The number of components (or “columns”) that the picker view should display.

Comment: So to clarify you have both? because they both are required.

Comment: And you said your array outputs in NSLog with desired results from CoreData

Comment: Yes I do have both. Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my question to reflect all the delegates I am currently using. Also when a breakpoint is set for the viewForRow and TitleForRow neither get called... I don't know if they should be or why they aren't.

Comment: Are these delegates methods called? Check by placing break point on each.

Comment: Yes @soulshined - the array reflects the changes and gets updated. I am using the AFNetworking library. But that shouldn't have any impact on this...should it?

Comment: Hi @Kampai I have set Breaks in each of them. All but the last two are getting called.

Comment: I know your better than this but we all make mistakes so just throwing it out there. Is UIPickerViewDelegate implemented in your header file

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence. and Yes it is. Any other thoughts...

Comment: Fuji if you've already created a property for pickerData there's no need to alloc init the array as an empty one on viewDidLoad that may be where the issue lays since your logic seems sound elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuji sir,

My recommendation would be as follows based on our conversation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [self printFromCoreData];
_ActiveDevice = [[NSString alloc]init];

// Connect data

self.DevicePicker.dataSource = self;
self.DevicePicker.delegate = self;
} 

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return _pickerData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return _pickerData[row];
}
```

And don't include reusingView unless you want to change the layout and add custom labels etc

Comment: this option does not work. The problem has never been with the array. It's more of a display issue.I am using Pods to run AFNetworking. I wonder if this would have an impact on pickerview?

Comment: I'm stumped then. Especially if your array gets logged @FujiRoyale

Comment: That makes two of us. I'm going to try the project without Pods attached. I don't think I actually need AFNetworking anyway as it will only parse xml or json.

Comment: It's not that I am using pods and AFNetworking. I've removed them and still the pickerview is not displaying.

Comment: @FujiRoyale oh I was assuming your data wasn't displaying. It's the picker view entirely? How was it implemented? Storyboard/code?

Comment: Storyboard and its nested in a view. I'm just thinking that perhaps I need to refresh the parent view as well thoughts?

Comment: @FujiRoyale okay. Your question was misleading. It states your data doesn't load instead of your picker view. We just wasted precious time conversing on that subject :) so to recap: you have a picker view set to hidden on launch and when FanDrop is pressed you want to load the picker view to display? Is picker view set to hidden via attributes tab in storyboard or is sent to the back of other subviews in the view?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading subject. Yes it is. I have removed that and tested the pickerview's ability to display data when not defaulted to hidden and still to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66419/discussion-between-fujiroyale-and-soulshined).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
      return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:        (NSInteger)component{
    return  [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not posting this in original question but I do actually have these in the view-controller. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: What's the data in your array? Can you NSlog this when view shows?

Comment: Yes. The data in the array is correct when this view shows.